# How To connect to mysql database with EntityFramework Core?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, connection-string

In the goal to use asp.net core mvc with the mysql database  , i have downloaded the [specific provider of EF_Core for Mysql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

Then i  registred ***the DbContext*** service in the startup file:

```
 services.AddDbContext<NawrasContext>(options=>
               options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and this is my *appsettings.json* :

```
  {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=s.mysql.db;Database=s2019;Uid=s2019;Pwd=pass;"

  }
}
```

I have successfully added my first migration , but when i try to update the database , i get this error :

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
  An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 's.mysql.db'.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
 at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 440
```

what i m doing wrong ?  why  the error is telling me  :

An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 's.mysql.db'.
while the name of the database in the connection string is specified ?

Comment: You should not include sensitive info in any question, Please replace your server, user and pass with any placeholder text for your own security

Answer (score 2):

Using these steps you can solve the issue

1. Use a Nugat package named "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql"
2. Register service to Startup.cs

```csharp
services.AddCors();

services.AddDbContext<NawrasContext>(options =>options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

3. Use this connection string in appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; Encrypt=true;"
  }
}
```

Comment: the server is online not localhost

Comment: Use connection sting like above [edited]  and let me know if it works or not

Comment: Hello Abdullah, am facing the same issue and the above solution did not solve it. Kindly take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61427947/12175082

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue using mac with MAMP as server for MySQL and the fix for me was to enable Allow network access to MySQL => Only from this Mac and then the server variable in connection string was like this :

```
"server=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;port=8889;user=root;password=MyAwesomePassword;database=MyAwesomeDb;"
```

so basically try to put the `mysql.sock` path instead of localhost.

hope this will help someone , thanks .