# Entity Framework Core Error: An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

I have made an `ASP.NET Core 3.1` Web-based application and want to use MySQL as the database.

I have been following along with some YouTube tutorials on creating `MySQL database` with `ASP.NET Core 3.1` *[code first approach]* including a tutorial from this site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I have created a `DataModel Class`, added a service to `UseMySQL` to the Startup.cs Class and created an `AppDBContext Class` that implements `DbContext Class`.

When I run this command in the **Package Manager Console**: `Add-Migration InitialDatabase` the application is creating a migration successfully.

When I run `update-database` it is throwing this exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'.
An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySQL' call.
```

When I call the `EnableRetryOnFailure();` function as required, I am facing this exception:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>         An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'. An error occurred using the connection to database '' on
>   server 'localhost'.

What could be the issue?
Where am I getting it wrong?

If you have links to useful articles about using `MySQL Database` with `ASP.NET Core` I would appreciate or your help on this particular issue.

I am using **Visual Studio IDE 2019** and **ASP.NET Core 3.1.1**

**Additional Code:**

This is the Startup.cs Class:

> ```
> private IConfiguration _configuration;
> public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
> {
>     _configuration = configuration;
> }
>
> // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddControllersWithViews();
>
>     // database connection string configuration  
>     services.AddDbContextPool<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseMySql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnectionString"),
>         mySqlOptionsAction: options => { options.EnableRetryOnFailure(); }
>         ));
>
>     services.AddMvc();
> }
> ```

**This is the connection string in appsettings.json:**

> ```
>   "ConnectionStrings": {
>     "DatabaseConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=MyAppDB;user=root;Password=123;"
>   }
> ```

Comment: The message indicates you have an empty connection string. What does your config file look like? (should be called `...EntityFramework.dll.config` or  `web.config` or `App.config`).

Comment: Are you using `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` or `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`?

Comment: Those are very good questions luker and Bradley. Let me post more code. I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql from Nuget

Comment: @luker: I have edited the question and added more code. I am using appsettings.json to store Database Connection string

Comment: @Bradley: I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: Hi. Could you solve issue? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: @Alvan Rahimli: I am yet to try the solutions offered here. Please try the solutions offered here and get back with feedback whether it worked for you. Also see the code by: YankTHEcode, Abdullah and the findings of Dominik.

Comment: I already solved problem. Some how i was not paying attention to server address. i was writing root@0.0.0.0 instead of just 0.0.0.0
it was dumb typo. 
By the way, problem occurs when ef can't establish connection.

Comment: @Rahimli: I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the root of the problem. This error also occurs when the connection to the database couldn't have been established. Make sure the information in your connection string is correct. This error message is very misleading, I spent couple of hours figuring this out because of it.

Comment: I really appreciate your findings. I will surely try your recommendation and if I get some errors or exceptions I will post. Your explanations make some sense. I appreciate!

Comment: In VS2022, .NET 8.0
Make sure that ConnectionString under "Connected Services" is correct. It didnt matter what connection string I added in appsettings.json
It would go to "Connected Services" -> "SQL Server Database" and take connection string from there

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way

1. Install package **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL**
2. Add services at **Startup.cs**

   services.AddCors();
   services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnectionString")));
3. change connection string at **appsettings.json**

   "ConnectionStrings": {
           "DatabaseConnectionString": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=MyAppDB;user=root;password="
         }

   *change the port number according to your MySQL server

   4.Run these commads at **Package Manager Console** for data migration
   Add-Migration InitialCreate

   Update-Database

You can look at the project at [github](https://github.com/mamun6/ASP.NET-Core-Sample-Project/tree/master/SampleProject-CodeFirst), for better understanding

Comment: I will try your approach and I really appreciate your time and response to this question.

Comment: I have tried your approach but still got an exception: fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'.
An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server 'localhost'.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.

Comment: is your project working with Microsoft SQL Server ? did you try it ?

Comment: Yes is it working with Microsoft SQL Server, I have tried it. However with MySQL I am facing these exceptions and I do not know where the problem is. I have tried to follow YouTube tutorials and examples from Microsoft Docs Website and even tried the implementation from Github as per your advice but for some reasons Visual Studio IDE is throwing these exceptions. I do not prefer Microsoft SQL Server due to its cost. Initially I preferred SQLite to MSSQL but found out that I may face concurrency issues with SQLite. Now I am left with MySQL as the only option, which is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just added the database port separately.

changed this from

```
MySQL": "server=mysqlserver.com:3306;user=db_user;password=db_pass;database=database_name"
```

to

```
MySQL": "server=mysqlserver.com;port=3306;user=db_user;password=db_pass;database=database_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string doesn’t seem to be right or EF is not able to pull it. You ll need to check the docs and select the correct project before running the update.
Confirm the connection string using this post:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/

You can try this workaround to specify the connection with the command, PS you ll need to update the provider name for MySql:

```
Update-Database -Verbose 
 -ConnectionString "CONNECTIONSTRING" 
 -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
 -StartupProjectName WEBSITE_PROJECT -ProjectName MIGRATION_PROJECT
```

Comment: Let me try your recommendation

Comment: The recommendation has not solved the issue unfortunately. Maybe there is somewhere I am missing it. I am still getting the exception.

Comment: Have you tried using integrated security instead of username and password in your connection string? And then try the above workaround command? I would first ensure that your connection string is correct!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link. Try to confirm your connection string value following that post.

Comment: Okay. I will try this approach

Comment: I am still getting the exception. When I use integrated security I get an error stating that integrated security is not supported. I wonder if EF Core 3.1 has issues with .NET Core 3 because I tried the demo tutorial from Microsoft and EF Website and still get the exceptions. I appreciate your help this far.

Comment: Can you share your db context file and the migration file that was produced?

Comment: I have decided to use SQLite with EF Core and ASP.NET Core 3.1. I was frustrated with the exceptions. I will post the DbContext file and Migration though. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this error occured the me when the connection string was wrong. In my case it was the port (by default 8457). Have you tried specifying it in the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Your steps don't seem to include installing a local instance of MySQL Server, which could be why you cannot find a server... because its not installed!

MSSQL (localdb) is bundled with Visual Studio 2019 ([with the Data Modelling and Processing workload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#installation-media)) but MySQL still needs to manually installed.

Have you tried installing a supported version of MySQL Server with your EF Provider?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This error occured when a MariaDB and the web app runs on the same host.
A hint for a solution you can find [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/#granting-user-connections-from-remote-hosts):

> Now that your MariaDB server installation is setup to accept
> connections from remote hosts, we have to add a user that is allowed
> to connect from something other than 'localhost' (Users in MariaDB are
> defined as 'user'@'host', so 'chadmaynard'@'localhost' and
> 'chadmaynard'@'1.1.1.1' (or 'chadmaynard'@'server.domain.local') are
> **different users** that can have **completely different permissions and/or passwords**.

In my case a user *mdbuser* is allowed to connect from hosts 192.168.178.% according to the table *mysql.user*.
So I added a second user named *mdbuser* with *localhost* and the error disappeared:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mdbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you forget to specify the Connection String in case of using SqlServer in NET6:

**Wrong:**

```
var conString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer());
```

**Correct:**

```
var conString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(conString));
```

Comment: Yeah, kinda duh.

Answer (score 0):

Suffered same error on IIS 8.5. The connection string was wrong, fixed it but error still showed.

Solution: Recycle the app pool. Changing the .json file doesn't restart de app so you need to do it.

Hope it helps somenone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a permission issue with AWS RDS.
I had to add an inbound rule in the security group with my IP. I was then able to connect

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that issue happened because I was trying to connect from the .NET Web Application running in a Docker Container to the MySQL installed in the machine where the Docker Container is running.

I thought everything was gonna run using localhost, but I realized every container runs in a specific local IP (like `172.17.0.2`) and also the local machine has its own local IP (like `172.25.224.1`) in the `Ethernet Adapter vEthernet (WSL)`.

When I changed the connection string to use the IP `172.25.224.1` instead of `localhost`, it worked fine.